# Show two images in one QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, image, qt, opacity, qgraphicsview

It's my first post here and I would like to say Hello Everyone on stackoverflow :)

OK, welcome already have been and now I specify the problem which I've got. I have one QGraphicsView widget and I want to show two images with some opacity in it, but my code doesn't work and I don't know what is the reason :/

```
QGraphicsScene *scenaWynikowa = new QGraphicsScene(ui->graphicsViewWynik);
ui->graphicsViewWynik->setScene(scenaWynikowa);
ui->graphicsViewWynik->fitInView(scenaWynikowa->itemsBoundingRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

//wyświetlenie zdjęcia nr 1
QImage obraz1(s1);
obraz1.scaled(QSize(541,541), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
update();
resize(541, 541);
QPixmap mapaPikseli1(n1);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem1 = scenaWynikowa->addPixmap(mapaPikseli1);
QGraphicsOpacityEffect poziomPrzezroczystosci1;
poziomPrzezroczystosci1.setOpacity(0.5);
pixmapItem1->setGraphicsEffect(&poziomPrzezroczystosci1);

//wyświetlenie zdjęcia nr 2
QImage obraz2(s2);
obraz2.scaled(QSize(541,541), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
update();
resize(541, 541);
QPixmap mapaPikseli2(n2);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem2 = scenaWynikowa->addPixmap(mapaPikseli2);
QGraphicsOpacityEffect poziomPrzezroczystosci2;
poziomPrzezroczystosci2.setOpacity(0.5);
pixmapItem2->setGraphicsEffect(&poziomPrzezroczystosci2);
pixmapItem2->moveBy(0, 0);

ui->graphicsViewWynik->show();
```

Sorry for not English Variable's names but it's more convinient for me. If you want I can explain what and why variable has that name :)
Maybe someone finds a mistake in this code and explain to me where's the problem with my code and how to fix it?

edit: It's my new code. When I move position of pix2 on QGraphicsView I can see two images (pix2 under pix1)and it works fine, but images should have opacity level to make a diffusion effect. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are trying to use two different `QGraphicsScene`s for your `QGraphicsView`. `QGraphicsView` can only have one scene.

What you should do, is create only one `QGraphicsScene` and add your pixmaps there.

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsScene->setScene(scene);
QPixmap pix1(n1);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem1 = scene->addPixmap(pix1);

QPixmap pix2(n2);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem2 = scene->addPixmap(pix2);
pixmapItem2->moveBy(0, pix1.height());
```

Also your `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` object is only valid inside the scope you created it in. One way to solve this problem is to allocate it with `new`.

```
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *opacity1 = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect;
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *opacity2 = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect;
opacity1->setOpacity(0.5);
opacity2->setOpacity(0.2);
pixmapItem1->setGraphicsEffect(opacity1);
pixmapItem2->setGraphicsEffect(opacity2);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for quickly answer but... I modified my code according to your tips and this code still doesn't work :/

Now, I have one scene and two pixmap Items but on QGraphicsView (after Build) I see only pixmapItem2. That's effect was before modification form your answer, too. In this methode, there's no other code. What's wrong?

Comment: @user3346580 Can you edit your question and add your new code to it?

Comment: @user3346580 Did you move your `pixmapItem2`? Maybe it's just on top of your `pixmapItem1`.

Comment: I edited my question. Take a look up of this topic and thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @user3346580 It seems like your `pixmapItem2` is on top of the `pixmapItem1`. Move it a little bit. See how I moved it in my code snippet.

Comment: I know how you moved it and I wrote that it works fine but I want to show one picture in backgraound and another in foreground with opacity (ex. 50%) to see the differences between pix1 and pix2. That code doesn't work fine because pix1 and pix2 hasn't no opacity effect even though I used QGraphicsOpacityEffect and .setOpacity to both of images.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thanks @thuga for your help. The problem has been solved. What was wrong? I was setting Opacity twice to two another variables but it was huge mistake. In QGraphicsView we can only declare OpacityEffect variable once, and assign it to multiple variables - just like QGraphicsScene.

Latest version of code (it works fine):

```
QGraphicsScene *scenaWynikowa = new QGraphicsScene(ui->graphicsViewWynik);
ui->graphicsViewWynik->setScene(scenaWynikowa);
ui->graphicsViewWynik->fitInView(scenaWynikowa->itemsBoundingRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

QGraphicsOpacityEffect *poziomPrzezroczystosci = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
poziomPrzezroczystosci->setOpacity(0.5);

QImage obraz1(s1);
obraz1.scaled(QSize(ui->graphicsViewWynik->width(), ui->graphicsViewWynik->height()), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
update();
resize(ui->graphicsViewWynik->width(), ui->graphicsViewWynik->height());
QPixmap mapaPikseli1(n1);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem1 = scenaWynikowa->addPixmap(mapaPikseli1);
QImage obraz2(s2);
obraz2.scaled(QSize(ui->graphicsViewWynik->width(), ui->graphicsViewWynik->height()), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
update();
resize(ui->graphicsViewWynik->width(), ui->graphicsViewWynik->height());
QPixmap mapaPikseli2(n2);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem2 = scenaWynikowa->addPixmap(mapaPikseli2);

pixmapItem1->setGraphicsEffect(poziomPrzezroczystosci);
pixmapItem2->setGraphicsEffect(poziomPrzezroczystosci);
pixmapItem2->moveBy(0, 0);

ui->graphicsViewWynik->show();
```

Comment: Each `QGraphicsPixmapItem` can have it's own `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`. You are not restricted to only single one.

Comment: Certainly it is, however, shown that I can not very advanced but also works I must be restricted to only single one because I want assign one level of opacity to both of images. In other cases it doesn't metter. I know :) Thanks a lot for your help.